# How to copy the value of different inputs via buttons to the clipboard? Java or Jquery (Without execCommand)

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

I try to make the `value` of the input copy to the clipboard with a button but I don't know how to make it copy the value with the related button.

I know that one of my errors is this `document.getElementById("main")` so the value "Main Title" is always copied. I don't know how I can copy the other `values`.
I'm trying to do this without using `execCommand` to save trouble in the future.

```html
<input type="text" id="main" value="Main Title">
<button onclick="copyCat(getAttribute('value'))">click</button>

<div class="options">
  <input type="text" id="a" value="Option A">
  <button onclick="copyCat(getAttribute('value'))">click</button>
  <input type="text" id="b" value="Option B">
  <button onclick="copyCat(getAttribute('value'))">click</button>
  <input type="text" id="c" value="Option C">
  <button onclick="copyCat(getAttribute('value'))">click</button>
</div>

<script>
    function copyCat() {
      var copyText = document.getElementById("main");
      copyText.select();
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Just pass the input field ID as a parameter ...?

Comment: Your issue isn't so much with the "copy" but rather "*how to get values and attributes from elements*" - that might help your research.

Comment: `Java != JavaScript && Java != JQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy the value of different inputs via buttons to the clipboard, you can make use of the Clipboard API (specifically the `navigator.clipboard.writeText` method).

1. Update the `copyCat()` function to take a parameter representing the `id` of the input element you want to copy from.
2. Use this `id` to select the appropriate input element.
3. Get the value of this input and copy it to the clipboard.

Here's the corrected code:

HTML:

```html
<input type="text" id="main" value="Main Title">
<button onclick="copyCat('main')">click</button>

<div class="options">
  <input type="text" id="a" value="Option A">
  <button onclick="copyCat('a')">click</button>
  <input type="text" id="b" value="Option B">
  <button onclick="copyCat('b')">click</button>
  <input type="text" id="c" value="Option C">
  <button onclick="copyCat('c')">click</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function copyCat(inputId) {
  // Get the input element based on the provided ID
  var copyText = document.getElementById(inputId);
  
  // Copy the value to the clipboard
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value).then(function() {
    console.log('Text successfully copied to clipboard!');
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error('Could not copy text to clipboard:', err);
  });
}
```

This approach works without needing the `document.execCommand` method.